# Visual Studio database project remote deployment fails. Unable to read local file?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a VS 2010 database project which I've had happily scheduled to deploy to my local development server every day with no issues. We're now approaching a release period and I'd like to start deploying to the remote UAT server instead, but it's now failing with "Error SQL01268 : Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened". I think this is down to one of the post-deployment scripts which contains lines like this :

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = (select * from OPENROWSET(BULK '$(OutputPath)\XML_1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as x);
```

(This xml is inserted into a table further on)

I'm guessing this is failing because the file isn't actually on the remote server, and it's only worked up to now because the server has been on the same machine as the deployment script.

Firstly, is that right? Secondly, does anyone know a way I can alter my deployment script to insert these xml files as part of the deployment without first having to copy them to the remote server (which I may not have that kind of access to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a possible solution, but it's not particularly pretty - sqlcmd mode.

Rather than trying to include the file in the SQL, I'm trying to include all the XML in the file before I run it.

e.g.

```
set @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
:r .\xml\XML_1.xml'
';
```

The main problem with this approach is that I have to include the xml declaration in the set, because the sql cmd code has to live on it's own line but there can't be a carriage return between the start of the xml file and the declaration.